# Request signature issue with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to do what the image is showing basically, but I keep getting `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

One thing I noticed is that my signature is shorter than what AWS has showed in their example so I know something is definitely wrong but I can't seem to figure out what.

```
def annotate():

    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            pass
        unique_filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
        file_name_prefix = f"folder_name/{unique_filename}~"
        object_name = file_name_prefix+"${filename}"
        s3_policy_conditions = [
        {"bucket": S3_BUCKET_NAME},
        {"acl": "private"},
        {"success_action_redirect": "www.success.html"},
        {"key":object_name}
    ]
        fields = {"key": file_name_prefix+"${filename}", "acl": "private"}
    # Generate presigned post request
        encoded_policy = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key=object_name,
        Fields=fields,
        Conditions=s3_policy_conditions,
        ExpiresIn=120  # 2 minutes
    )
        print(encoded_policy)
        return render_template('annotate.html',data=encoded_policy)
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle errors appropriately
                error_response = {
                    'code': 500,
                    'status': 'error',
                    'message': str(e)
                }
                return jsonify(error_response)
```

This is the code for my AWS signing. And below is my code for extracting my signed policy and use it to POST.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Upload VCF File</h1>
    <form id="upload_form"
      action="{{ data['url'] }}" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
    >
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ data['fields']['key']~filename }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private">
      <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="vkodagi-hw3.mpcs-cc.com:5000/annotate/files" />
      <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="{{ data['fields']['AWSAccessKeyId'] }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="{{ data['fields']['policy'] | tojson}}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{ data['fields']['signature']}}" />
      Select input file: <input id="upload_file" type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Input File" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my signature small? I have tried to do a simple upload to the server, then I upload to the s3 bucket and that works. So I can guarantee that my credentials are correct.
[image]

Comment: Try again using `s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))`

Comment: Thank you. It works now. Also had to pass my access key and secret access key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of your pre-signed URL being shorter than you expected it to be is because you are using signature v2 signing.

You should be using [signature v4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html), which can be done as follows (add your credentials as needed):

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```